# VLC player streaming doesn't starts when shell script executed from php file

Tags: php, cvlc, powershell

My project is to start RASPI camera streaming from Android APP. When android app clicks a button, HTTP POST method accesses a PHP page on RASPI. This PHP page executes shell script which opens VLC to start streaming webcamera.

php script  : `shell_exec('nohup /home/pi/startvlc.sh &');`

startvlc.sh file :

```
cvlc  v4l2:///dev/video0 --v4l2-width 640 --v4l2-height 480 --v4l2-chroma MJPG --v4l2-hflip 1 --v4l2-vflip 1 --sout '#standard{access=http{mime=multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=--7b3cc56e5f51db803f790dad720ed50a},mux=mpjpeg,dst=:8554/}' -I dummy
```

Somehow this approach is not working. I have other similar script to run omxplayer which works fine. I suspect this to be some permission issues ? Please help